# zendesk - semantic template array accessor

Tags: zendesk

Is there a way for me to access a particular element of an array using Zendesk semantic templating. https://connect.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010914668-Using-the-email-editor#topic_h2z_hn5_r1b

Normally you would go through each element of the array

```
{% for image in 'images' | EventProperty %}
  <img src="{{ image.src }}">
{% endfor %}
```

But for my current use case I only need the first element. I wanna do something similar to the following:

```
<img src="{{ images[0].src }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks like Liquid Markup, and I know they use Liquid in other areas of the product.  Have you tried the [Liquid Filter 'first'](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/first/)?

```
{% assign my_array = "apples, oranges, peaches, plums" | split: ", " %}

{{ my_array.first }}
```